# Populate array with data, typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, lodash

How to populate an array with following structure:

```
ProjectsTimeSlots: Array<{ProjectName: string, Id: number, DefaultEmployeeId: number,
    TimeSlots: Array<{
      StartTime: Date, Duration: number
    }>
  }>;
```

With json data that have only `ProjectName, Id, DefaultEmployeeId` fields.
Is there a way to do that with lodash.js or without it?

Comment: Make an interface or a class or something - of course there is a way to do that without lodash.js, what do you think people used before JS libraries? How do you think people write JS libraries?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sample json can look like this:

```
var json = [
{"ProjectName": "Name", "Id": 1, "DefaultEmployeeId": 1, "TimeSlots": [] },
{"ProjectName": "Name 2", "Id": 2, "DefaultEmployeeId": 111, "TimeSlots": [{"StartTime": new Date(Date.parse("01.01.2000")), "Duration": 12}] }
];
```

Note, that you sould be responsible for Date serialization/deserialization.

#### Update 1.

If your json has the `ProjectName`, `Id` and `DefaultEmployeeId` fields you can just assign it

```
ProjectsTimeSlots = [
{"ProjectName": "Name", "Id": 1, "DefaultEmployeeId": 1 },
{"ProjectName": "Name 2", "Id": 2, "DefaultEmployeeId": 111 }
];
```

or, if you want to add the `TimeSlots` property then map it:

```
ProjectsTimeSlots = [
{"ProjectName": "Name", "Id": 1, "DefaultEmployeeId": 1 },
{"ProjectName": "Name 2", "Id": 2, "DefaultEmployeeId": 111 }
].map((item) => { item.TimeSlots = []; return item; });
```

or push items in forEach loop:

```
ProjectsTimeSlots = [];
var json = [
{"ProjectName": "Name", "Id": 1, "DefaultEmployeeId": 1 },
{"ProjectName": "Name 2", "Id": 2, "DefaultEmployeeId": 111 }
];
json.forEach((item) => { item.TimeSlots = []; ProjectsTimeSlots.push(item); });
```

#### Update 2.

This code enhances an existing array with a new field (`TimeSlots`):

```
var array = [
    {"ProjectName": "Name", "Id": 1, "DefaultEmployeeId": 1 },
    {"ProjectName": "Name 2", "Id": 2, "DefaultEmployeeId": 111 }
];
array.forEach((item) => { item.TimeSlots = []; });
```

Comment: I am asking how to dynamically populate an array with data.

Comment: This isn't working for me, just show me please how to enhance an existing array with a new field. I think this will be easier.

Comment: but then it tells me there is no such a thing as item.TimeSlots

Comment: `array.forEach((item) => { item["TimeSlots"] = []; });` or cast item to <any> should help